# Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Comment Automation

Tags: comments, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Today I have a question about Google Apps Scripts, specifically for *Spreadsheets*. I've already looked at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range) (yes, documentation on a *Sheet* within a Spreadsheet), but I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for. Here's the sitch:

1.) When a cell is edited in a Google Spreadsheet, the function I have SETS a *NOTE* using the function (yes it says *cell.setComment()*, but in reality it creates a Note. Thanks for being consistent, Google!):

```
function onEdit() {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet();
var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
cell.setComment("Last modified: + (new Date()));
}
```

2.) Notes have been 'replaced' by *Comments* as of... September 5th, 2012? Maybe? I would rather use those instead.

3.) For both types of 'cell notation', there exist functions only to *SET* the Note/Comment, and not *ADD* (according to the documentation).

4.) I would like to reference or write a function that has the capability to ADD a new Note/Comment (preferably Comment, they are more easily read), instead of setting the Note/Comment.

5.) You can MANUALLY add a Note/Comment through the GUI in the Spreadsheet itself (right-click a cell and select "Insert Note" or "Insert comment". Because these right-click functions exist leads me to believe that we could write a script to do the same thing, but have it be called auto-magically when the cell has been edited.

6.) This function will be used to keep track of cell revision history. I know that I can create a new spreadsheet and send the revision history to that new spreadsheet easily, but considering that I have 10 spreadsheets that need to be tracked, I would rather not have 10 new spreadsheets to keep track of history. Keeping it in the same spreadsheet will keep things simple.

If anyone could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no way to manipulate Comments via Spreadsheet Services - see [Issue 36756650](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756650). (Star it if you wish.)

Instead, all the "Comments" methods work on Notes.

The following method will append a new "Modified" timestamp to any existing one - not quite as nice looking as an actual Comment would be, unfortunately.

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var comments = cell.getComment();
  // Newline works in msgBox, but not in Note.
  comments = comments + "\\nModified: " + (new Date());
  //Browser.msgBox(comments);
  cell.setComment(comments);
}
```

Comment: Haha, I'm "commenting" right now XD

Thank you very much Mogsdad. I'll subscribe to that issue so that I can change my script when it is fixed. In regard to your code, I can't believe that I missed such a simple solution... get() the old 'comments' and append to them with newlines. You're a genius, and you just made my job at work much much easier!

Comment: How to get comment contents and author name or email?

Answer (score 10):

Updated answer for dic 2018:

Now Google supports the setNote(String) and setNotes(Object[]) method in the Range class.

the getComment() and setComment() methods no longer exist.

Comment: do we have any solution to add links inside cell notes?

Comment: @Jaswinder - no we do not, unfortunately - see [this recent Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511838/google-drive-api-ignores-anchor-parameter-when-creating-comments-in-a-spreadshee?noredirect=1#comment111063722_57511838) for details

Answer (score 8):

Using [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/insert) in Google Apps Script, we could create Comments in a Google Document.
And after a test, I confirm you can also do it in a Spreadsheet (which is normal because Comments depends only on Drive API)

```
function insertDriveComment(fileId, comment, context) {
  var driveComment = {
    content: comment,
    context: {
      type: 'text/html',
      value: context
    }
  };
  Drive.Comments.insert(driveComment, fileId);  
}
```

Keep in mind that you cannot attach programmatically the comment to a cell (or to words in Google Document), because anchors for Document and Spreadsheet Comments are proprietary (check the video at the bottom of the page [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-comments))
Hope it could help.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use setNote() and getNote()

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
 var comments = cell.getNote();
 cell.setNote(comments);
```