# Insert the entire contents of one Google Doc into the comment of another

Tags: google-apps-script, comments

The problem
I'm interested to know if it is possible to copy the entire contents of one Google Doc and paste into a comment in another Google Docs using keyboard commands.

Background- 
I do a lot of grading of student papers and have a range of standard comments I use which are individually stored in separate documents.  I use Macros and keyboard shortcuts in MS Word to grab the contents of the comment file I want and put it into a comment in the paper I'm grading. I edit the macro files using the VB editor when necessary. It works quite efficiently.

I found some related material in my research, however this don't quite match what I am trying to do.

I think the code from here [Insert comment into Google doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331280/insert-comment-into-google-doc) does something like what I want, but kind of the opposite.

Google Apps Scripts is new to me. I'm not really looking to become a programmer, I just need to know if developing such a script is possible or not and how hard it would be. I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: I just inserted the contents of one of my documents into a comment in another document. So I guess the answer is yes.  Actually you do have to use a mouse click to complete the comment

Comment: Hi Cooper. I guess what I am interested in is setting up a Google App Scrip that does the same as the macro I use in MS word. I trigger the macro with keyboard commands. A dialogue box opens and then with one mouse click I can choose the file I want to import into the comment in the document I'm editing. I don't have to open the source (comment) document, the macro "imports" the text into the comment in the document I'm editing. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

### A sample to point you into the right direction:

```
function myFuction()
{
  var fileOriginId='PASTE HERE THE ID OF THE FILE WITH THE COMMENT TEXT';
  var fileDestinationId ='PASTE HERE THE ID OF THE FILE WHERE THE COMMENTS SHALL BE INSERTED';
  var text=DocumentApp.openById(fileOriginId).getBody().getText()
  var comment={ 'content': text};
  Drive.Comments.insert(comment, fileDestinationId);
}
```

[image]

This code snippet passes the whole contents of a Google Docs document to the variable `text`. Subsequently, the contents of `text` is inserted as a comment into a second Google Docs document. It uses the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) that needs to be [enabled](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) beforehand.

- Should you desire to pass only a part of the text in the original file into the comment, e.g. a paragraph, you would need to chose the specific paragraph instead of the whole document body.
- Should you desire to append the comment to a certain text within the destination document, you need to use the optional property `context.value`, as done in the reference you provided.

> Please find here references to useful documentation that will help you
>   udderstand Apps Script and adjust the code snippet provided to your
>   requirements:

- [DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/) to access Google Docs documents
- [Body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body) of a document
- Retrieve [children](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#getchildchildindex) of a document
- [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)
- [Enable Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Insert comments](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/insert) with Advanced Drive Service

Comment: That looks like exactly what I needed... thank you. Much appreciated.