# Is it possible to copy comments and suggestions when copying a Google Doc using Drive API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-api-python-client

I noticed that comments and suggestions are not by default copied when using `drive.files.copy`. This is imperative to my project, so I did some googling and it seems like this feature may not even exist? I thought about copying and applying the comments manually using the Docs API, but I can't seem to find anything helpful about this on SO or the Google API documentation for Drive and Docs. Does anyone know if this is possible and how to do this?

Thanks

edit: the `comments.list` method returns comments, but not suggestions. I think I would be able to insert these comments manually into the copied document. What about suggestions? Is there a way to retrieve these?

It would be really nice if I could easily copy both without a lot of leg work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Unfortunately it's not possible to copy a Google Docs file with comments and suggestions

- As for comments, you can copy-paste them manually like done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57656668/11599789).
- However, suggestions are different from comments (at least as the Google APIs go) - see [here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/suggestions) for information.
- In order to retrieve suggestions, you can use the [documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) method
- Yet, inserting suggestions programmatically is currently not possible - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60776585/11599789) for more details

Answer (score 0):

If you download the document as a word file, and re-upload it it will maintain both comments and suggestions I think! It seemed tow work for me.