# Adding a note to a cell in Google Drive spreadsheet using C#

Tags: c#, google-apps-script

I'm currently working on a C# program to write a set of test results to a spreadsheet on Google Drive, and under the current format the cell to which I'm writing has one data value in the cell and the other 5 in a note (not a comment) on the cell.

EX: 1.8 visible in the cell, and when the cursor hovers over said cell, a small box appears to the side containing

Average: 1810 ms

Highest: 1921 ms

Lowest: 1708 ms

StdDev: 78 ms

Median: 1787 ms

My program currently can access and write to the cells in the Google spreadsheet, but I can't find a way to create a note for the cell and write to that. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556476/google-apps-script-spreadsheet-comment-automation), setting a comment in the described way will actually add a note to the cell. This might be a known issue for them but I guess works in your favor. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: the issue is that the linked api doesnt add a comment, adds a note instead. since its only in apps script, google how to call the apps script from c# using an apps script contentservice and a published url as anyone, anonymous

Comment: They've actually fixed this issue, and now instead just have a setNote() method in the Apps Scripts. Unfortunately, this now raises the issue of how to utilize the Apps Scripts from my project (which I think is what Zig is saying to do).