# How to GetComments from google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to get comments from google sheets based on cell range in my script program But found that range.getComment() method is deprecated and now returning notes only.

Please let me know what is the replacement of getComment() method or what are the other ways to get comments from google sheet in my script program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Comment Automation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556476/google-apps-script-spreadsheet-comment-automation)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, it looks like Google Apps Script can only retrieve the notes from a range:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNotes()

There is no equivalent getComments() function.

This is an issue that has been officially raised here: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1818

One of the developers has noted that:

> We are aware of the demand for this feature, but there is no work going on at the moment. As a partial solution, you can use the Drive Advanced Service to read all the comments and replied on a spreadsheet, but you aren't able to create new comments or determine to which cell a given comment is attached to.

So it is possible to grab all comments, just not which cells those comments are associated with.

Comment: Finding the associated cell would mean decoding the internal range in the workbook-range anchor, see this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56544407/how-to-get-a-cell-range-from-google-drive-comments-api - not sure if that's possible, could be through another internal lookup table

Answer (score 4):

First you need to enable the Drive Api service, and then use `Drive.Comments.list` with your `file_id`:

```
function getComments() {
  var comments = Drive.Comments.list(file_id).items;
  Logger.log(comments);
}
```