# Google Apps Script: Get list of users "assigned" to a google doc and comments

Tags: google-apps-script

In google docs, when commenting on something, you can type "+" to 'assign' a user to an item. I'm wondering if there's a way to get the list of "assigned" users in a google doc (and maybe filterable by status - resolved/done/etc).

I've seen some other posts stating that getting comment data isn't possible within the Documents Apps script, but that it is possible with the Drive API. Can the Drive API be used in a Google Sheets script? If so, could it be used to get the information mentioned above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to GetComments from google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839057/how-to-getcomments-from-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

The Advanced Drive API can get a list of all comments in a spreadsheet but I don't think it will achieve what you are looking for as you can't tell which cell the comments are attached to.

I don't think you will be able to assess the assigned status using this method.

Comment: Thanks Brett. I don't suppose the answer is any different for GDocuments (not spreadsheets)?

Comment: Yes it is the same for all as it is the Advanced Drive API and not specific to the file type. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/