# How to get a cell range from Google Drive Comments API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to find out to which cell a comment belongs to in Google Spreadsheet. From the API I get

```json
{'kind': 'drive#comment',
   ...
   'anchor': '{"type":"workbook-range","uid":0,"range":"285502171"}',
   ...}
```

Yet I am unable to transform the integer-valued `range` to the appropriate cell range (i.e. `A1:A2`) in the spreadsheet. According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-comments#anchoring_comments) the anchor should look completely different. Based on the doc I'd assume that there is supposed to be a *region* class of type `matrix`. There is no mention of `workbook-range` in the doc in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from this [SO related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498275/creating-anchored-comments-programmatically-in-google-docs),

The [Anchoring Comments](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-comments#anchoring_comments) feature from the Google Drive API is intended for **non-Google Docs editors files**, not for **Google Documents**. Unfortunately, at this time the Document Service from Google Apps Script doesn't include a Class Comment to handle comments and discussions.

You could probably do this with non-Google editor files.

Comment: I do not get the design than. If it is supposed to be used for _non-Google Docs editors files_ why does it provide comments _from_ the individual Docs?

Comment: I am not sure, that is the best answer for the original question. The original question is about comments in a Google Spreadsheet. So this is actually a **non-Google Docs editors file** from my point of view: non-**Google Docs** specifically, it is Google Sheets. ;-)
I would be very interested in finding out how that workbook-range can be decoded because of this other issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839057/how-to-getcomments-from-google-sheets

Comment: And the irony in this is that Google mentions spreadsheets multiple times in the documentation for [Anchor Region Classifiers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-region-classifiers). Meanwhile people have been asking about this [for over 10 years](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756650).