# How to resolve comment and convert it to cell's Value?

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

Please Help, how to convert comment's value to cell's value using google script?

This is the comment, and i want to getValue that comment, and setValue to each cell:

1st Picture:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/oecno.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oecno.png%5D)

2nd Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPo6t.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to GetComments from google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839057/how-to-getcomments-from-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

Try this? Select cell with comment and run code.

```
function moveComment() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var comments = cell.getComment();
  cell.setValue(comments);
  cell.setComment("");
}
```

Comment: Where does that `getComment()` come from? I couldn't find it in the documentation...

Comment: Class Comment  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/comment

Comment: That's for Sites, so you can't use it with spreadsheets or ranges.

Comment: You are correct it is for Sites. It worked for me in Sheets. My guess is because it is Google Apps Script Class.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, Google Apps Script cannot do exactly what you want:
access a comment for a specific cell of your choosing.  It also cannot determine what cell a comment is attached to.

You can see question [15556476](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556476/google-apps-script-spreadsheet-comment-automation) for additional information. Even better, please go star Google's Issue [36756650](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756650), and hopefully that will prompt them to release this functionality we all want.

There aren't any references to Comments within [the current API for Spreadsheet ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).  And, in the Drive Comments API, [the "anchor" property](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-comments) does not work with Spreadsheets.  (Also see question [56544407](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56544407/how-to-get-a-cell-range-from-google-drive-comments-api).)