# Is it possible to add a comment attributed to specific text within Google Docs using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

Google docs comment:

[image]

My goal is to add a text-specific comment using Google Apps Script as seen in the picture above. Right now I have this working code, but it only adds a general comment for the whole document.

```
function myFunction() {
  var fileId = '{FILE_ID}';
  var resource = {'content': 'comment body text'};
  Drive.Comments.insert(resource, name);
}
```

Comment: Is this for a custom file or a Google Apps file(like a doc or a sheet)

Comment: Google docs, yes!

Comment: As @AL. wrote it is not possible for Google App Files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. In this video -- [Google Drive SDK: Announcing the Comments API](https://youtu.be/ZBU52nacbLw?t=5m30s) (5:30 - 5:39) -- it is mentioned that:

> ..We do have a proprietary anchoring scheme, which does make it difficult for, or actually rather impossible for you to create comments that are anchored to text in our document formats...

"*in our document formats*" refers to Google Docs and Sheets.

This is also mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181280/4625829). For more details regarding Comments, you can check the [Manage Comments and Discussions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-comments) documentation.

Comment: 5 years later, and this is still the case? 

Comment: 2023 - still the case