# Is there any hover-like trigger for Google Apps Script in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

#### Thanks - I'm learning because of you

*Thanks to the great posts and comments on stackoverflow, I've learned so many ways to enhance my use of Google Ads (my primary role) via the JavaScript-like Apps Script and now I've moved on to integrating with Google Sheets. Bravo stackoverflowers for your commitment to helping others!*

## Question

**Is there any way to trigger a script attached to a Google Sheets document that would fire on hovering?** We have a spreadsheet that contains tabs for the current month's online advertising budgets for a client by month. We duplicate the previous month's tab rather than just adding a column to the existing (previous month) tab because we sometimes added notes in a merged set of cells before we discovered how easy a popup HTML window could be implemented.

I cannot find anything in the scripts guides or via Google searches, but I am using a button that is prominent (just an inserted drawing attached to a script) that can be clicked to pop up an HTML file that explains the documents overall purpose.

Ideally, there would be something that displayed when hovering over a cell or button, but we could also live with something where a popup "speech bubble" would display on the entering of a cell.

Unfortunately, as we all know, there is no "onFocus" event.

With that in mind, are there *any* options that might accommodate hover, entering a cell but not changing the values, etc? Anything that might allow for tooltips, popups or other guidance to someone reviewing a spreadsheet without an accompanying text document.

Thanks in advance for reading - I've included a screenshot of the way I've currently implemented a per-sheet button that provides notes on specific changes for that tab.

[image: Screenshot of Google Sheets with HTML popup and button displayed]

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: There aren't hover-like triggers but you could use notes or comments for showing a text related to a cell.

The docs about triggers are

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

An the related event objects are listed in

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Here is how a cell with a "hidden" note looks

[image]

Here is how a cell and a displayed note looks

[image]

Cell notes could be inserted from the UI and by using Google Apps Script, i.e. [setNote(note)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setNote(String))

Related

- [Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Comment Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15556476/1595451)