# Function to get comments on Google Slide with Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I can´t seem to find a way to get the comments made in a Google Slide.
If anyone knows please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15583355/7215091

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by comments? You mean the [speaker notes](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/notes) or comments as you can have in Sheets or Docs?

Comment: Comments as in Sheets or Docs

Comment: I posted an answer regarding this. Please let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Drive API for this.

If you make a call to [Comments: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments) and provide the ID of your presentation, you will get the list of all comments in this presentation.

#### Reference:

- [Comments: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments)
- [Comment resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments)