# How Can I add comment on a cell using google sheet app script

Tags: javascript, automation, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

How Can I add comment to google sheet using app script. I can add notes but i want to add comments. tried different methods but no clue.

> .setcomments

and

> .getcomments

function not even exisit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Comment Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556476/google-apps-script-spreadsheet-comment-automation)

Comment: @MikeSteelson i wonder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achive to add a comment with :

```
function insertDriveComment(){
  var fileId = 'your file id'
  var resource = {'content': 'Here is my comment !'};
  Drive.Comments.insert(resource, fileId)
}
```

you have to enable Drive API service

or, if you use the same spreadsheet to add comments

```
function insertDriveComment(){
  var fileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()
  var resource = {'content': 'Here is my comment !'};
  Drive.Comments.insert(resource, fileId)
}
```

to enable drive api service
[image]

Comment: Where is field id?

Comment: file id is the id located here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=342925622 You can fetch it by script with `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()`

Comment: if i want to add comment to specific cell?

Comment: Not possible! Notes are tied to a specific cell but comments are tied to a file. The Drive API only supports file-level comments on blob files. But you can add text inside the involved cell.